# How to start node through gulp-nodemon with a flag?

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodemon

How to start node through gulp-nodemon with a flag?

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    // listen for changes
    livereload.listen();
    // configure nodemon
    nodemon({
        // the script to run the app
        "script": 'server.js',
        "ignore": ["*.test.js", "logs/*"],
        "ext": 'js',
        env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development', 'DEBUG':'*' },
    }).on('restart', function(){
        // when the app has restarted, run livereload.
        gulp.src('server.js')
            .pipe(livereload())
            .pipe(notify('Reloading page, please wait...'));
    })
})
```

I'd like to start it with the flag DEBUG=* for using it with the debug library. However its not accepting it through env. Adding it after the script name results in an error.

How do I add a flag to nodemon within a gulp script?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/issues/85). It is suggested there to set `stdout: true` or to use the `exec` option, i.e.:

```
nodemon({
    ...
    exec: 'node DEBUG=*'
});
```

If this does not work you can try the options `args` and `nodeArgs` shown in [this issue](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/issues/89), i.e.:

```
nodemon({
    ...
    args: ['DEBUG=*']
});
```

I did not try these approaches myself but I hope they will help.

Comment: thx Jonas, just updated debug version and realized its not using a flag, but an env var now instead.

Comment: Alright, I will leave my answer this way, maybe it will point others into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Debug is not any more using a flag like you can read it in several blog posts. It now uses an env variable instead.

```
nodemon({
    "script": 'server.js',
    "ignore": ["*.test.js", "logs/*"],
    "ext": 'js',
    "env": { 'NODE_ENV': 'development', 'DEBUG':'*' },
})
```

or by running it with env var on shell

```
DEBUG=* node server.js
```